# Read AVCHD files to QTMovie on Mac OS 10.8

Tags: macos, quicktime

I really want to read AVCHD files to QTMovie. I found that Quicktime player can read AVCHD file on Mac 10.8 so does Mac OS 10.8 have API to read AVCHD file to QTMovie or another object.

I tried some function like

- [[QTMovie alloc] initWithFile:(NSString*)]
- NewMovieFromDataRef()

but it did not work.

So does anyone have any idea for this?